# How do deal with single quotes when invoking powershell.exe from cmd.exe

Tags: powershell

Please see sample below which fails to work due to how cmd.exe interprets single quotes looks like.

`powershell.exe -Command "& {param($a) ConvertFrom-JSON $a }" -a '{"name":"greg"}'`

```
C:\>powershell.exe -Command "& {param($a) ConvertFrom-JSON $a }" -a '{"name":"greg"}'
ConvertFrom-JSON : Invalid JSON primitive: greg.
At line:1 char:14
+ & {param($a) ConvertFrom-JSON $a } -a '{name:greg}'
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

Comment: `cmd.exe` doesn't interpret single quotes at all. It is the PowerShell CLI that strips the `"` around `"name"` and `"greg"`, which explains the symptom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The *Windows PowerShell* CLI (`powershell.exe`) requires `"` chars. that are to be preserved as such to be escaped as `\"`.<sup>[1]</sup>

  - Note: *PowerShell (Core) 7+*'s CLI (`pwsh.exe`)  now also accepts `""`, which *when calling from `cmd.exe`* is actually preferable for robustness.<sup>[2]</sup>
- There is no point in trying to split the CLI arguments into a PowerShell script block and its arguments, because the PowerShell CLI simply stitches together multiple arguments - after stripping syntactic enclosing double quotes -  into a single, space-separated string and then evaluates the result as PowerShell code.

Therefore, try the following:

```
C:\>powershell.exe -Command "ConvertFrom-JSON '{\"name\":\"greg\"}'"

name
----
greg
```

---

<sup>[1] By contrast, PowerShell-*internally* it is `` ` ``, the backtick, that serves as the escape character.</sup>

<sup>[2] E.g. `pwsh.exe -c " Write-Output ""a & b"" "` outputs `a & b`, as expected, whereas

`pwsh.exe -c " Write-Output \"a & b\" "` *fails*, because `cmd.exe` - due to not recognizing `\"` as an *escaped* `"` - considers the `&` *unquoted* and therefore interprets it as its *statement separator*.</sup>

Comment: Shouldn't it work as well when you escape them by surrounding them with quotes like this: `powershell.exe -Command "ConvertFrom-JSON '{"""name""":"""greg"""}'"`  ?

Comment: @Olaf, that works too, but it (a) offers no advantage over `\"`and (b) is nonstandard, whereas `\"` is the most widely used convention for escaping `"` on Windows. That said, the most _robust_ escaping _when calling from `cmd.exe`_ is `""`, which, however, only PowerShell (Core) 7+ supports.

Comment: I've always used back ticks to escape, thought that was the norm

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, the backtick-escaping applies to _PowerShell code_, but here we are talking about arguments passed _externally_ to PowerShell's _CLI_ where - perhaps surprisingly - different rules apply _at first_ (after these rules are applied, when using `-Command` / `-c`, backtick-escaping may _additionally_ be necessary, but not in this case).

Comment: @Santiago, this is for cmd.